# Rails javascript development: debug vs releases

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm starting a Rails app which will use a lot of javascript. What's the best way to approach that? I would like to have my scripts nicely formattet while developing, but would like to have one of these "nicely" compressed, single file includes when deploying my app.

I would assume that there is some functionality which handles that automatically. Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 3.1 will have that baked in, but for now I'd recommend using Jammit: http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/